# Accessing to the database Integer type

Tags: c#, ms-access

i have a problem here.
I already create a textbox that connect to the database in windows app, but this textbox is string type and is working successfully, on the second form i created an array of textboxes that connect to the database, but this time is int type.
how do i access that textbox to the database that int type?

Here is my code for second form, i using an array of textboxes:

```
OleDbDataReader dReader;
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Code] FROM [Data] ORDER BY [Code] ASC", conn);
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        while (dReader.Read())
        {
            namesCollection.Add(dReader.GetInt32(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code"));
        }

        textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;

        dReader.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

Somehow,the while (dReader.Read()) is error, i dont know how to solve this, can anyone help me please? Thanks

Comment: @Myndwave: the error is not tell anything, there is no error, just when i run the program, the autocomplete for Int type is not working

Comment: @GrantWinney: already try those kind of things that you gave me, but the result still same >.<

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletestringcollection.add.aspx), the only `Add` method for `AutoCompleteStringCollection` is:

```
public int Add(string value)
```

So try converting your integer to a string before adding it to the collection:

```
namesCollection.Add(Convert.ToString(dReader.GetInt32(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code")));
```

Comment: the error message is not showing anything, just when i run the program, the autocomplete not working.

Comment: one question, how do i convert my integer to a string?

Comment: i already try "namesCollection.Add(Convert.ToString(dReader.GetInt32(dReader.GetOrdinal("Code"))))
but it is doesn't work either